# How to mute ringtone while clicking power button or volume up or down when i receiving IncomingCall in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-service

In my Android Application we are done with **VOIP** calls.I handled both incoming and outgoing SIP Calls.Now my question is during app to app call i receiving incoming call to my app,that time i am getting default ringtone from device and playing that ringtone using **RingtoneManager**.Then i clicked *power* button or *volume* up or down button ringtone is not ***muted*** like normal phone calls.How to mute incoming ringtone while clicking power button and volume up or volume down button.Is there any Clicking Event available? How to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope this can help you a bit. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788834/9388338

Comment: When you receive a call, you are probably creating an activity to notify the user, right? If yes, you can override onKeyDown() method and check if the user pressed power or volume keys and then, you can stop the tone.

Comment: thanks @W0rmH0le its working...but still i click power button it doesnot works..

Comment: Checking here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-intercepting-physical-key-events--mobile-10379 It seems you can't override Home and Power button actions.

Comment: you found anything? I'm trying to achieve the same ... with the power button too

Comment: Any idea to stop from service/background

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        ringtone.play();
```

Playing ringtone by this way you can stop ring tone by pressing volume buttons without implementing any other thing.